# C++: Read a delimited file and store in a structure

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I'm new to programming, so I could use your help with my code. I am trying to read an existing file that has data formatted like this:

```
2012-09-22|microsoft|0|102.36|100
2012-09-22|apple|0|203.12|100
2012-10-05|ibm|0|141.96|100
2012-10-05|boeing|0|123.65|100
2012-11-03|sears|0|23.36|100
2012-11-29|toyota|0|78.45|100
```

I am posting all of my code, but the relevant function is the void loadData(transaction allTransaction); function. I hacked this code together from multiple examples I found here, but it's not working for me. I am trying to read in the data and then populate the variables of the allTransaction structure. I then want to push that structure to the data vector. I want to loop each line until I reach the end of the file. It looks like I am not getting the values of the structure populated. Please help!

I've only been doing this programming for 2 months now for school, so please keep your responses to noob level.

Thanks

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE // Declaration to use deprecated code in Visual Studio.

#include <iostream> // Include the iostream standard file.
#include <string> // Include the string library.
#include <fstream> // Include to manipulate files.
#include <vector> // Include to use vectors.
#include <sstream> // Include to use stringstream.
#include <ctime> // Include to calculate time.

using namespace std;

// Create transactions structure
struct transaction
{
    /*int user = 0;*/
    string date = "";
    string stock = "";
    bool sale = 0;
    double price = 0.0;
    int shares = 0;
};

// Create vector
vector <transaction> data;

// Function declarations
void loadData(transaction allTransaction);
void buyShares(transaction allTransaction);
void sellShares(transaction allTransaction);
void storeData(transaction allTransaction);

int main()
{

    // Declare variables
    transaction allTransaction; // Declaring a structure.

    loadData(allTransaction);

    cout << "Date: " << allTransaction.date <<
        "Name: " << allTransaction.stock <<
        "Sale?: " << allTransaction.sale <<
        "Price: " << allTransaction.price <<
        "Shares: " << allTransaction.shares;

    //Pause program
    cout << "Press Enter To Continue..." << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}

// Load text file function
void loadData(transaction allTransaction)
{

    string line;
    ifstream myfile("data.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            istringstream f(line);
            string s;
            while (getline(f, s, '|')) {
                myfile >> allTransaction.date >>
                    allTransaction.stock >>
                    allTransaction.sale >>
                    allTransaction.price >>
                    allTransaction.shares;
                data.push_back(allTransaction);
            }
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "Unable to open file";

}

// Buy stock function
void buyShares(transaction allTransaction)
{
    allTransaction.sale = 0; // Set sale boolean to 0, indicating a buy.
    storeData(allTransaction); // Call storeData function to store the data.
}

// Sell stock function
void sellShares(transaction allTransaction)
{
    allTransaction.sale = 1; // Set sale boolean to 1, indicating a sell.

    // Need function to check shares on hand.

    storeData(allTransaction); // Call storeData function to store the data.
}

void storeData(transaction allTransaction)
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("data.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    myfile << allTransaction.date << "|" << allTransaction.stock << "|" << allTransaction.sale << "|" <<
        allTransaction.price << "|" << allTransaction.shares << '\n';
    myfile.close();

    data.push_back(allTransaction);
}
```

Comment: Please consider being a little more specific in what your problem is. What have you tried, what isn't working. Off the top of my head, many of your routines pass your transactions by value when they should be passed by reference. Otherwise you are modifying a _copy_ of the transaction, not the original transaction itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that pops into my eyes is this loop:

```
while (getline(f, s, '|')) {
    myfile >> allTransaction.date >>
        allTransaction.stock >>
        allTransaction.sale >>
        allTransaction.price >>
        allTransaction.shares;
    data.push_back(allTransaction);
}
```

First you read from the istingstream f with the delimiter '|' (which is a good thing) but within the while loop body you once again read from the file (which is not what you want). You may do something like this.

```
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    while (getline(f, s, '|')) {
      v.push_back(s);
    }
    if(v.size()!=5) {
      std::cerr << "expected 5 values" << std::endl;
      return false; // or throw an exception etc...
    }
// At this point you have a vector with the strings 
// delimited by '|' ready for processing
// into your allTransaction class
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, is there no way to skip the push into the vector and load the values directly into the structure?

Comment: @JPark Of course. But the example wouldn't have been simple.